# Differences and use cases of "net", "network", "mesh", "grid"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences, synonyms

What are the differences between *net*, *network*, *mesh* and *grid*?

If I have a look at the OED entries, I have a feeling of rather a circular definition:

> *mesh* Material made of a network of wire or thread...
>
> *net* A piece of open-meshed material...
>
> *grid* A network of lines that cross each other...

Could you list some most common collocations with each of the words and explain why this particular one is used? Such as why do we use *mosquito net* [and not](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mosquito%20net%2Cmosquito%20mesh&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmosquito%20net%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmosquito%20mesh%3B%2Cc0) *mosquito mesh*?

Comment: A net is what you use to catch things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference lies partly in the physical properties of the different nouns, and partly in their intended use.

A *mesh* is what all these terms have in common; it's a weaving of some thread-like substance into a regular-polygonal pattern (typically the polygons are squares, but not necessarily). The polygons are generally expected to all have equal size, and any type of weaving involving non-polygonal patterns - a knitted sweater for example - is not considered a mesh. A window screen for keeping insects away is a good example of a mesh; a metal [chain-link fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-link_fencing) is a good example of one not based on squares.

A *grid* is a mesh that's flat - for example, U.S. city streets are usually organized in a square *mesh* pattern, but we call this pattern a *grid* because it's basically flat (the earth it lies on is flat).

A *net* is a mesh that is **not** necessarily flat; it's made of flexible material. Thus, fishing nets can be wrapped into a bag-like shape for hauling in fish. This also explains, as you asked, why we say *mosquito net* and not *mosquito mesh* - although *mesh* could be sort of appropriate if we're talking about a fixed mesh (like the wall of a tent), intended to keep mosquitos out but not intended to be used for catching them (as a *net* would be used).

(So in general: we say *net* if we're talking about a mesh whose purpose is to capture, contain, or exclude something.)

Finally, a *network* has the least in common with the above three because it doesn't necessarily follow a regular pattern. *Network* never refers to any of the above terms; it refers to *irregularly patterned* systems of connection. Computer networks, for example, contain many connected computers, but their physical proximity to one another is completely arbitrary.